# Cannot get return value from captcha in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-recaptcha

I get problem when get return value from captcha Vue Js. 
This is my script :
[image]
and
[image]

I want get captchaResult for save function, but captchaResult is undefined.

This is the result.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can mix `setup` and `data` syntax.

I.e., use either the "Composition API" (setup) or the "Options API" (data).

Try removing the following block and see if it works:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    capthaResult: null,
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I try your solution but still undefined.
Yes, I want get result from setup -> checkValidCaptha.
Can you tell me, how to fill data from Composition API (setup) to Option API?